# Listview not showing data in hybrid mobile app using Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i am new for ionic with angular apps and i am trying to display listview using below code but i am getting exceptions as below shown can some one suggest me how can resolve this problem

```
'arrayList' is declared but its value is never read.
      L9:  export class HomePage {
      L10:    private arrayList:Array<any>=[];
      L11:    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }
```

### home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DetailPage } from '../detail/detail';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  private arrayList:Array<any>=[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
   }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.arrayList = [{name:"Ramakrishna1",email:"rk1@gmail.com",phoneNumber:"8008824731"},
    {name:"Ramakrishna2",email:"rk2@gmail.com",phoneNumber:"8008824731"},
    {name:"Ramakrishna3",email:"rk3@gmail.com",phoneNumber:"8008824731"},
    {name:"Ramakrishna4",email:"rk4@gmail.com",phoneNumber:"8008824731"},
    {name:"Ramakrishna5",email:"rk5@gmail.com",phoneNumber:"8008824731"},
    {name:"Ramakrishna6",email:"rk6@gmail.com",phoneNumber:"8008824731"},
    {name:"Ramakrishna7",email:"rk7@gmail.com",phoneNumber:"8008824731"},
    {name:"Ramakrishna8",email:"rk8@gmail.com",phoneNumber:"8008824731"},
    {name:"Ramakrishna9",email:"rk9@gmail.com",phoneNumber:"8008824731"}];
  }
}
```

### home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      ListView
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let list of arrayList" text-wrap>
            <h2>{{list.name}}</h2>
            <p>Email: {{list.email}}, Number: {{list.phoneNumber}}</p>
          <button ion-button clear item-right (click)="goToDetails(list)">View</button>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable arrayList is private, thus you cannot access it in the template in `--prod`-mode. And without getting read in the template it's considered unused by the linter.

Turn it into

```
arrayList:Array<any>=[];
```

With no `private`. The default access modifier is public and you need it to be public to be readable in the template.

Comment: can you please edit my code because i am beginner,Then i can able to solve my problem

Comment: i tried but list not showing and also not exceptions

Comment: Have you set up your module correctly? I assume you are following some kind of a tutorial. Please check the module configuration, if all the ionic imports and providers match

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/javascript/1355/ionic-2-tutorial-with-angular-typescript

Comment: i followed above tutorial but small change in array List

Comment: its working for me 2 hours ago but suddenly not working

Comment: Try to remove anything involving ionic in the template and just use regular html-tags with regular angular directives (*ngFor) and see if it works. If it does, something with your ionic configuration is wrong. I also strongly recommend learning Angular first before using external Ionic components. At least do first chapters of the Tour-Of-Heroes tutorial to understand how to setup the app